# What's a good way to get started integrating ADFS with AzMan?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, authorization, federated-identity, adfs

Does anyone know of any good screenscasts or documentation covering the integration Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with Authorization Manager (AzMan)?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the responses as an answer or elaborate on what is still outstanding?

Answer (score 5):

There are many links I would recommend, screencasts are always a good way to get started:

***Channel 9 Screencasts***:

*AzMan*

[Demystified Series: Getting Started with AzMan](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-Getting-Started-with-AzMan/)

[Demystified Series: Programming AzMan](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-Programming-AzMan/)

[Demystified Series: AzMan in the Enterprise](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-AzMan-in-the-Enterprise/)

[Demystified Series: AzMan on Windows Server Code Name “Longhorn” and Windows Vista](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-AzMan-on-Windows-Server-Code-Name-Longhorn-and-Windows-Vista/)

*ADFS*

[Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) Part 1 by Keith Brown](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-Active-Directory-Federation-Services-AD-FS-Part-1/)

[Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) Part 2 by Keith Brown](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/donovanf/Demystified-Series-Active-Directory-Federation-Services-AD-FS-Part-2/)

***Documentation / Articles***

[Whitepaper on Developing Applications Using Windows Authorization Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480244.aspx)

[MSDN Article on using Role-Based Security in Your Middle Tier .NET Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300469.aspx)

[Role-Based Access Control for Multi-tier Applications Using Authorization Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780256.aspx)

[Role-Based Access Control Using Windows Server 2003 Authorization Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952386.aspx)

[Security Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480465.aspx)

***Blogs***

[ADFS Documentation Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/adfs_documentation/default.aspx)

[ADFS Product Support Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/adfs/)

[Identity and Access Blog (A .NET Developer's Resource)](http://blogs.msdn.com/donovanf/default.aspx)

[Security Briefs (Keith Brown's Blog)](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/keith/default.aspx)

[Authorization Manager Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/azman/)

[Federated Identify Blog](http://identity-des.com/)

[T4 Toolbox: Strongly-typed AzMan wrapper generator](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/12/t4-toolbox-strongly-typed-azman-wrapper-generator/)

That's probably more than enough for now, hopefully some of these links will be useful in helping you understand AzMan and how it's role-based access control (RBAC) capabilities can be employed in the claims-based programming model that ADFS uses.

Comment: Many of these are useful, and I've been through many of them, but they each cover the technologies individually. I'm looking for documentation on integrating the two.

Comment: The paragraphs directly under the 'Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS)' heading towards the end of the Whitepaper are all about integrating/mapping the two with code examples included.  Quote: "The primary step in integrating Authorization Manager with ADFS is to map the..."

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to avoid AzMan and go to ADFS v2, aka "Geneva".
or you could use the [.NET Access Control service.](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/accesscontrol.mspx)

Comment: Azure has nothing to do with this!

Comment: Sorry?  The question was about an access control capability.  How can you say that an Access Control service is irrelevant?  It's directly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Having been down the Azman road I recommend you take a look at this:
[link text](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/)

To do anything passed role checks with MS AZMan you end up having to make COM calls. Plus the other is open source making it a lot easier to extend for ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300469.aspx).